# See output from another user account

Tags: command-line, ssh

So here's the setup:

I have a remote computer running a program directly in CLI from user account NN. If I SSH into the same user account NN, is it possible to see the output of the program running in the first user account instance from the second instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the program is logging its output into a file, I'd say "no, not directly".

However, there *is* a way of achieving what you want. Use `screen`, which is a virtual console multiplexer:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen

(You can also use [`tmux`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) which is more modern, but I'm not familiar with that so my answer will talk about screen).

Once you get `screen` installed:

- Log into the remote system.
- Start `screen` (just type `screen`, then read the intro screen, press space).
- You'll see what looks like a standard command prompt. It is, however it lives inside one of `screen`'s virtual consoles.
- Start your program here.
- When you want to leave your program working and log out, first "detach" `screen`. This "detaches" it from your actual terminal but screen (and the program contained inside it) continue running. The program thinks it's connected to an actual terminal so it will see no difference. To do this, press `ctrl-a`, then `d` (`ctrl-a` is `screen`'s control prefix). You'll go back to a command prompt.
- To reconnect to a running `screen` instance, type `screen -rd`. This will bring back `screen` and your running program.

You can of course detach and then log out entirely. When you log back in, you just `screen -rd` to get your "session" back.

`Screen` can do a lot more than that, you can have multiple "consoles" open, switch between them, copy and paste data, and even use split views and fancy stuff like that.